# what can be the error with system crash and return 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isna'

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5, nan

I have a python script that uses pandas and pyqt5  where the user loads a csv file in a qtableWidget and prints the records that include **NaN values** then the user can drop these records.
in order to drop the Nan values the system takes the user input through QInputDialog.

The problem occurs when the user drops the NaN values and try to print the records the system crash and display the below error:

> self.display_nan.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_df_NaN(self.df))
> File "f:\AIenv\sentiment_analysis\qt_designer\harak_anal_2_mainUI.py
> .py", line 189, in print_df_NaN
> print(self.df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isna'

## code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import pandas as pd

from PandasModel import PandasModel

import seaborn as sns
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px 
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline.offline import iplot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QLineEdit
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
     
      
        self.loadBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select File", self)
        self.loadBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)

        self.display_nan = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Display  NaN Values", self)
        self.display_nan.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_df_NaN(self.df))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.display_nan, 3, 0, 1, 1)
       

        self.drop_nan_value = QtWidgets.QPushButton("drop  NaN Values", self)
        self.drop_nan_value.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getText())

     
        self.pandasTv = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pandasTv)

    def loadFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
        self.pathLE.setText(fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
        model = PandasModel(df)
        self.pandasTv.setModel(model)
        self.df = df
   

    def print_df_NaN(self,df):
        print(self.df[df.isna().any(axis=1)])

    
    def getText(self):
        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "select the column to drop NaN","column name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed and text != '':
            print(text)
            self.df = self.df.dropna(subset = [text] , inplace=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Should be: `print(self.df[self.df.isna().any(axis=1)])` you missed the `self.`

Comment: i add the self  and still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pandas documentation for [DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

> inplacebool, default False
>
> If True, do operation inplace and return None.

This means that the line

```
self.df = self.df.dropna(subset = [text] , inplace=True)
```

effectively sets `self.df` to `None`. The solution is to either use

```
self.df.dropna(subset = [text] , inplace=True)
```

Or

```
self.df = self.df.dropna(subset = [text] , inplace=False)
```